# How much depth does the NXT battery pack add?

Tags: nxt, battery

The NXT rechargeable battery pack does not fit flush with the back of the NXT brick like the battery cover (used with 6xAAs) does.  I don't have the battery pack (yet), so I was wondering how much depth it adds.  I found [a picture](http://www.nxtprograms.com/help/parts/9797.html) of the pack installed, which gives the impression that it may be a brick taller, or maybe only a stud taller.  Exactly how much though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It adds the same thickness as a studless beam indeed, or 8mm / 20 ldu.

(This is true for the grey 9VAC battery, but I suppose it holds for the white 10VDC one as well)

Comment: My white 10VDC battery pack arrived today.  It adds the same thickness as a studless beam, same as the 9VAC battery pack.