# Dimensions of Mindstorms NXT pieces

Tags: mindstorms, piece-information, size

I don't have access to my NXT boxes at the moment (they're stuck behind a wardrobe that won't get moved for a week or so) and I'm working on this project where I need to know the dimensions of the NXT, motors and sensors in mm. I did a search but couldn't find anything on the net and was wondering if anybody knew what the dimensions (height, width, depth) of the NXT brick, motors, US sensor, color sensor (the one in NXT 2.0 that works as a lamp and light sensor also) and touch sensor?  Thanks

Comment: Do you just mean "in studs/bricks" or are you after the actual dimensions in mm?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid sorry I should've specified that.  I'm after the dimensions in mm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just measured them myself. Some of the dimensions might be just a little bit off, but I hope this suffices:

**NXT:**

Length: 111 mm

Width: ~71.7 mm

Height: 40 mm ([extra 8 mm if you have a rechargeable battery installed](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/802/129))

**Motor:**

Length: ~105 mm

Width: 40 mm

Height: ~45 mm

**Ultra-sonic Sensor:**

Length: 44 mm

Width: 44 mm

Height: 30 mm

**Generic Sensor:**

Length: 44 mm

Width: 22 mm

Height: 30 mm

If it's a touch sensor and the button is not pressed, then it's 47 mm long.

Again, some of these may be a bit off since some dimensions were difficult to properly measure with the ruler I was using due to the geometry of some of the pieces. If you want a more accurate and precise measurement, someone else might be better equipped to answer your question.